# Getting Json data from https client

Tags: android, json, http, https

I'm trying to fetch Json data from an https client . I know how to get Json data from http client . I'm wondering is there any way to do ?

When I'm using api.androidhive.info/contacts as json url it is working. But when I'm using jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/56aa6129e4b01190df4c0b87 as json url it isn't . Because the former is http and the later is https.

I used okHttp client but it didn't work .

Here is my MainActivity

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    final int CONN_TIME = 1000 * 15;
    final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    TextView txtView;
    String ans;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.screen);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        SyncUserDataAsyncTask s = new SyncUserDataAsyncTask();
        s.execute();
    }

    public class SyncUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,    JSONArray> {

    // User user;

        SyncUserDataAsyncTask() {

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                 CONN_TIME);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONN_TIME);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS);

            JSONArray returnedArray = null;
            try {

                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                ans = result;
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                if (jArray.length() == 0) {
                    returnedArray = null;
                } else {
                    returnedArray = jArray;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return returnedArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray returnedArray) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            // callBack.done(returnedArray);
            //super.onPostExecute(returnedArray);
            txtView.setText(ans);
        }
    }

}
```

Updated MainActivity

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    final int CONN_TIME = 1000 * 15;
    final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/56aa6129e4b01190df4c0b87";

    TextView txtView;
    String ans;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.screen);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        SyncUserDataAsyncTask s = new SyncUserDataAsyncTask();
        s.execute();
    }

    public class SyncUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        // User user;

        SyncUserDataAsyncTask() {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url(SERVER_ADDRESS)
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                return response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String returnedArray) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            // callBack.done(returnedArray);
            // super.onPostExecute(returnedArray);
            if (!returnedArray.matches(""))
                txtView.setText(returnedArray);
        }
    }

    private static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            } };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts,
                    new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext
                    .getSocketFactory();

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
             okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
            okHttpClient.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;

                }
            });

            return okHttpClient;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
02-10 15:57:40.855: I/ActivityManager(353): Displayed com.assignment.dipper/.MainActivity: +5s99ms
02-10 15:57:43.741: W/art(1459): Verification of boolean okhttp3.internal.Util.skipAll(okio.Source, int, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) took 150.654ms
02-10 15:57:43.801: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:43.857: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:43.986: W/art(1459): Verification of java.lang.String okhttp3.internal.Util.toHumanReadableAscii(java.lang.String) took 234.971ms
02-10 15:57:44.097: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:44.207: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:44.298: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:44.407: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:44.736: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459): Process: com.assignment.dipper, PID: 1459
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at com.assignment.dipper.MainActivity.getUnsafeOkHttpClient(MainActivity.java:125)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at com.assignment.dipper.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:82)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at com.assignment.dipper.MainActivity$SyncUserDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:60)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at com.assignment.dipper.MainActivity$SyncUserDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     ... 4 more
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at okhttp3.internal.tls.RealTrustRootIndex.<init>(RealTrustRootIndex.java:31)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at okhttp3.internal.Platform.trustRootIndex(Platform.java:97)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at okhttp3.internal.Platform$Android.trustRootIndex(Platform.java:271)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:189)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:60)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:718)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at com.assignment.dipper.MainActivity.getUnsafeOkHttpClient(MainActivity.java:123)
02-10 15:57:44.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     ... 9 more
02-10 15:57:45.085: W/ActivityManager(353):   Force finishing activity com.assignment.dipper/.MainActivity
02-10 15:57:45.146: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:45.297: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:45.407: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:45.513: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:45.584: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:45.605: D/gralloc(52): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
02-10 15:57:45.619: E/libEGL(52): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
02-10 15:57:45.620: E/SurfaceFlinger(52): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 0
02-10 15:57:45.620: E/SurfaceFlinger(52): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
02-10 15:57:45.759: W/WindowManager(353): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (320x480) to layer 21015
02-10 15:57:45.760: E/ActivityManager(353): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 192x192
02-10 15:57:45.890: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 111 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:46.714: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 530 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:46.822: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 388 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:46.917: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 118 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:47.287: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 231 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:47.367: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:47.381: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:47.564: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:47.664: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:47.845: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 89 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:48.105: I/Choreographer(628): Skipped 1189 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:48.181: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 144 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:48.404: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:48.591: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 187 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:48.648: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 152 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:48.805: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 95 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:48.895: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 73 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:49.030: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:49.020: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:49.171: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 79 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:49.237: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:49.331: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 1612 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:49.360: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 107 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:49.429: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 103 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:49.521: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:49.627: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 116 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:49.728: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 122 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:49.803: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:49.929: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:50.043: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:50.207: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 101 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:50.342: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:50.457: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:50.587: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 543 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:50.655: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 118 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:50.818: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 178 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:50.947: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 123 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:51.055: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 296 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:51.079: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 139 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:51.284: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 209 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:51.460: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 110 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:51.548: I/Choreographer(628): Skipped 633 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:51.631: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 105 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:51.890: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 405 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:52.029: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:52.216: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:52.738: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:52.922: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 269 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:52.984: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:53.247: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:53.341: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:53.437: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:53.596: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:53.681: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:53.759: I/Choreographer(353): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:54.064: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.assignment.dipper.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{22cc757d V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-187,166} that was originally added here
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at com.assignment.dipper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-10 15:57:54.349: E/WindowManager(1459):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-10 15:57:54.374: I/Choreographer(1459): Skipped 125 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-10 15:57:54.557: W/WindowManager(353): Failed looking up window
02-10 15:57:54.557: W/WindowManager(353): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@2aacfcff does not exist
02-10 15:57:54.557: W/WindowManager(353):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8412)
02-10 15:57:54.557: W/WindowManager(353):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8403)
02-10 15:57:54.557: W/WindowManager(353):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2558)
02-10 15:57:54.557: W/WindowManager(353):   at com.android.server.wm.Session.remove(Session.java:186)
02-10 15:57:54.557: W/WindowManager(353):   at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:197)
02-10 15:57:54.557: W/WindowManager(353):   at com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact(Session.java:130)
02-10 15:57:54.557: W/WindowManager(353):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Comment: You know how to get data from the httpclient. Are you looking for other ways to do the same ? The question is unclear. Please clear it a bit

Comment: When I'm using http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/ as json url it is working. But when I'm using https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/56aa6129e4b01190df4c0b87 as json url it isn't . Because the former is http and the later is https

Comment: unclear? there is no question in this question other than: *I'm wondering is there any way to do ?*  on which the obvious answer is: yes, there is.

Comment: Post your code what you have done.

Comment: @RonakJoshi I have posted the code have a look at it

Comment: @Selvin updated the question

Comment: I actually just have the same problem with latest okhttp version and "unsafe" trust-all-ssl okHttpClient.
Your question maybe should not be "is it possible with https?", but "why do i get an exception when using https in this case?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 private static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {

    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }
            }
    };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
    final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = client.newBuilder();
    builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
    builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;


        }
    });

    return builder.build();

}
```

Comment: hey you haven't defined okHttpClient in your post .

Comment: this is a method call it like this,
`OkHttpClient  client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();`

Comment: I got that. I mean't to say that in the last section where you are returning okHttpClient ,you haven't defined okHttpClient variable in this scope to make it unsafe ,then how did it become unsafe ?

Comment: Boukharist have a look at updated MainActivity in my post. In method getUnSafeOkHttpClient() after defining okHttpClient eclipse is giving following error:- The method setSslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory) is undefined for the type OkHttpClient

Comment: which version of the Okhttp library are you using ? the code I gave you is working for the 2.0.0 version

Comment: It is latest one 3.1.1. I integrated it to my eclipse project from http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: I updated the code , actually in this version you should use the builder.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. I have posted the logcat

Comment: ANSWER:

(cant officially answer as this question is ON HOLD).

This wont work, as the current version of OkHttpClient does crash on build(), if you have trustmanagers returning NULL at getAcceptedIssuers().
My current workaround is to retrieve the first default trustmanager, and getAcceptedIssuers() uses the original trustmanager to retrieve the issuers.

Comment: apparently square has solved the issue , this code should be working by version 3.1.2, try it @pratik saxena.
More deatails in [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1475)

Comment: I replaced with lastest 3.1.2, still the same exception rises:

    02-11 15:26:02.841: E/AndroidRuntime(4320): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    02-11 15:26:02.841: E/AndroidRuntime(4320):  at okhttp3.internal.tls.RealTrustRootIndex.<init>(RealTrustRootIndex.java:31)

Comment: yeah starting version 3.1.2 "getAcceptedIssuers()" should return an empty array instead of returning null, Please see the edit I hope it works this time.

Comment: I had this line missing "return new X509Certificate[0];" . Adding it made my app work. Problem appeared after moving to Retrofit2 package and Okhttp3. Thanks